# fullcalendar multiple cell select on mobile device?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, fullcalendar

I have created a fullcalendar application for mobile device like Android and iPhone using Phonegap. I am using the [Jquery Touch Punch Plugin](https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js) along with the Jquery fullcalendar plugin. The 'select' method of fullcalendar is working fine on the web. I am able to select multiple cell on the month view of the full calendar on web browser. However, on the native android/iPhone app I am not able to select multiple cell(range of dates) of the calendar. All that happens is when I click on the cell to select range of dates then the 'select' method is triggered before allowing me to select multiple dates on the device. Is there anyway to overcome this issue? Thank you in advance. Here is the [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/17/).

sample code:

```
// FullCalendar v1.5
// Script modified from the "theme.html" demo file

$(document).ready(function() {    
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month'
    },
    editable: true,
    disableDragging: true,
    disableResizing: true,
    droppable: true,
    drop: function( date, allDay, jsEvent, ui ){
       console.log(jsEvent);
       console.log(ui);
    },
    // add event name to title attribute on mouseover
    eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {            
        if (view.name == "month") {
            $(jsEvent.target).attr('title', event.title);
        }
        //alert(event.id);
    },
    // For DEMO only
    // *************
    events: [
        {   id: 1,
            title: 'User1',
            start: '2012-09-01',
            end: '2012-09-01',
            color:'#E9B33E',
            className: 'user-class1'},
        {   id: 2,
            title: 'User2',
            start: '2012-09-06',
            end: '2012-09-06',
            color:'#00813E',
            className: 'user-class2'},    
        {   id: 3,
            title: 'User3',
            start: '2012-09-06',
            end: '2012-09-06',
            color:'#E59238',
            className: 'user-class3'},     
        {   id: 4,
            title: 'User4',
            start: '2012-09-06',
            end: '2012-09-06',
            color:'#00813E',
            className: 'user-class4'},            
        {   id: 5,
            title: 'User5',
            start: '2012-09-08',
            end: '2012-09-08',
            color:'#00813E',
            className: 'user-class5'},
        ],
    eventRender: function(event,element,calEvent) {                   
        element.attr('id',this.id);
        if(this.id!=5){                    
            element.find(".fc-event-title").after($("<br/><span class=\"fc-event-icons\"></span>")
            .html("<img src=\"http://png-5.findicons.com/files//icons/2018/business_icons_for/16/passport.png\" onclick=\"javascript:iconsAlert("+this.id+",'passport')\" class=\"icon\"/>"+
                "<img src=\"http://findicons.com/files//icons/1571/chalkwork_payments/16/card_visa.png\" onclick=\"javascript:iconsAlert("+this.id+",'visa')\" class=\"icon\" />"+
                "<img src=\"http://findicons.com/files//icons/894/banking_stuff/16/postage_stamp.png\" onclick=\"javascript:iconsAlert("+this.id+",'traveldoc')\" class=\"icon\" />"+
                "<img src=\"http://findicons.com/files//icons/756/ginux/16/richtext.png\" onclick=\"javascript:iconsAlert("+this.id+",'entrystamp')\" class=\"icon\" />"));
        }
        element.droppable({
                accept: '*',
                tolerance: 'touch',
                //activeClass: 'ui-state-hover',
                //hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
                drop: function(ev, ui) {                
                    //console.log(ev.id);
                    alert(this.id);
                    //for(param in ui){    console.log(ev.id);}
                }
              });
},
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   alert("Cell selected from "+$.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd')+" to "+$.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
},
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    if (!$(jsEvent.target).hasClass("icon")) {
       alert("UserID:"+calEvent.id);
    }                
}

});


$('#external-events div.passport-event,.visa-event,.entrystamp-event,.traveldoc-event').each(function() {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            className: $(this).attr('class')
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });

    });
});
```

[Humble request to moderators: Please do not close this question unless it is resolved. Thanks]

Comment: is there any console output from Mobile Safari? $(document).ready() might be an issue as well as jQM uses $(document).bind('pageinit') http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: @PhillPafford could not see anything in the console. Thank you so much for taking a look into this. Please take a look into http://jsfiddle.net/veer712/KrZJr/17/ as well

Comment: If you're trying click + drag, then take heart in the fact that I had to settle with click-click too. :)

Comment: I am not too familiar with jQuery Mobile, but I don't think touch+drag works the same way as click+drag. Maybe you should think of alternatives here - like maybe having checkboxes on each slot for selecting. Also, it might be that FullCalendar just is not optimized for mobile, and can't handle the touch+drag.

Comment: @MahavirMunot, can you take a look at a combination of these - 1) don't use the `select` callback, 2) bind the `swipe` mobile event to `.fc-day-content` (or any better element you want from the rendered calendar), 3) based on the `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` passed to this event-handler, use `.elementFromPoint(x,y)` to get the selected days, 4) using this call the `select` method to programmatically select the days swiped. This is a hack at best - let me know if that helps! All the best!

Comment: You could take a look at this... http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mobiledraganddrop It is still in development, but it may be useful. After looking at the touch punch plugin, there doesn't seem to be any kind of method for dragging only for simulating mouse down up and click events...

Comment: Need some code to see where the jQuery is failing, than can assess the functionality, to ensure the form does not get submitted every time the day is clicked

Comment: @ShaunOReilly I am using the jquery touch punch. That's all I added for making the fullcalendar work on mobile device. I made the drag and drop events work on mobile device. However, the touch and move(selectable) doesn't works. You may take a look at https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js . Do I need to make some change in this touch punch file. You may use JsFiddle in case if you find something. Thanks a ton for responding.

Comment: @ganeshk thanks for providing hint. Also I will check the http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/mobiledraganddrop

Comment: Just a heads-up, even the inbuilt calendar app in iOS doesn't support multiselect. It provides a start and end date in the create event dialog, where you can change the end date. Maybe you could do something similar. I had achieved this earlier for desktop version - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/xgSTr/) - maybe that'll help!

Comment: @ganeshk Yes, that's an alternate option left with me if I am not able to achieve the multiselect. Thanks. Meanwhile if you still find something please let me know.

Comment: @MahavirMunot I am also having same issue of selecting multiple days in Full Calendar on handheld devices, But not using jQuery Touch Plugin. Is Full Calendar not supported of selecting multiple days on handheld devices?  Have you got any solutions?

Comment: @ganeshk .elementFromPoint(x,y) can be slow when this event fires so much... I have a solution similar to what you recommend in my answer

Answer (score 2):

How about adding event listeners to the cells of already initialized calendar and applying some magic, like this:

```
$('#calendar table.fc-border-separate td.ui-widget-content').on('touchstart', function (event) {
    /* touch start processing, probably cancelling like*/ 
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    function mouseMoveHandler (event) {
         /* processing actual drag */
         /* possible also cancelling default behavior and instead calling Calendar API */
    }

    function mouseUpHandler (event) {
        /* processing mouse up */

        /* some clean up */         
        $(document).off('touchmove', mouseMoveHandler)
        .off('touchend touchleave touchcancel', mouseUpHandler);
    }

    $(document).on('touchmove', mouseMoveHandler)
        .on('touchend touchleave touchcancel', mouseUpHandler);
});
```

I know this is a bit low-level comparing to the rest of your code, but that can help.
These events will only work on mobiles and probably you will be able to achieve the desired behavior.  Sorry no time to try this approach myself, maybe I'll try that later on jsFiddle.

Comment: I have try but not work.. Please can you tell me when put this code or fiddle

Answer (score 1):

This answer was found in another StackOverflow post: [How can we specify custom date range with fullcalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397474/how-can-we-specify-custom-date-range-with-fullcalendar)

You can call this function to get events from a date range. However, this will bring you only 30 days events.

```
function GetAgendaEvents(datefrom, dateTo) {
    var fromDate = new Date($("#from").val());
    var toDate = new Date($("#to").val());

    if (fromDate.getTime() <= toDate.getTime()) {
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEvents').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

        var filteredEvent = $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
            return event.start >= fromDate && event.start <= toDate;
        });

        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('gotoDate', fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate());
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agenda'/* or 'basicDay' */);

        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEvents').fullCalendar('addEventSource', filteredEvent);
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution is  Datebox. i've implemented it in my jquery mobile application , its easy to use. and very good for both on computer,mobile,tblet 
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/

Comment: Not relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to this old question...

A solution without touch punch:

I have personally implemented the fullcalendar for mobilie and was having trouble with the touchmove handling of multiselect so I decided to do it all just based on the html day objects themselves.

I just get the height/width of what is first selected and count the distance moved in relation to that height/width. It requires a SelectDates(date1, date2) function to handle whatever you want to do with the daterange your select.

Here is my code:

```
        $(document).on('touchmove', '.fc-day', function (e) {
            var touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] || e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];

            var $startElement = $(this);
            var moveStartDate = new Date($startElement.data('date'));
            var timezoneOffset = moveStartDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
            moveStartDate.setTime(moveStartDate.getTime() + timezoneOffset);

            var rect = $startElement[0].getBoundingClientRect();

            var DayHeight = $startElement[0].clientHeight;
            var DayWidth = $startElement[0].clientWidth;

            var xdif = 0;
            if (touch.pageX < rect.left) {
                xdif = touch.pageX - rect.left;
            }
            if (touch.pageX > rect.right) {
                xdif = touch.pageX - rect.right;
            }
            var xDaysAwayDecimal = xdif == 0 ? 0 : (xdif / DayWidth);
            var xDaysAway = xdif >= 0 ? Math.ceil(xDaysAwayDecimal) : Math.floor(xDaysAwayDecimal);

            var ydif = 0;
            if (touch.pageY < rect.top) {
                ydif = touch.pageY - rect.top;
            }
            if (touch.pageY > rect.bottom) {
                ydif = touch.pageY - rect.bottom;
            }
            var yDaysAwayDecimal = ydif == 0 ? 0 : (ydif / DayHeight);
            var yDaysAway = ydif >= 0 ? Math.ceil(yDaysAwayDecimal) : Math.floor(yDaysAwayDecimal);

            var dayModifier = (yDaysAway * 7) + xDaysAway;

            var moveEndDate = new Date(moveStartDate);
            moveEndDate.setDate(moveEndDate.getDate() + dayModifier);
            if (moveStartDate > moveEndDate) {
                SelectDates(moveEndDate, moveStartDate);
            }
            else {
                SelectDates(moveStartDate, moveEndDate);
            }
        })
```

Also.. if your SelectDates() does any heavy lifting, you might want to only have it fire every x amount of pixels moved or x amount of millisecond... either that or just save off the values then do the processing when you stop. My SelectDates() added css to the calendar so I wanted it to fire continuously with the touch move motion.

Comment: Im sure you js wizards can probably implement this same sort of solution in a more elegant fashion, but I thought the idea might be helpful to anyone having this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of searches I found no simple and clear answer, So, I made it by myself, and here it's:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     .. 
    ....
     ..
    dayRender: function( date, cell) {
        $(cell).on("touchend",function(event){
            var startDate = date;
            var x= event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientX;
            var y = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY
            var endDate = moment($(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).attr("data-date"),"YYYY-MM-DD");
            if(endDate>startDate){
                calendar.fullCalendar( 'select', startDate, endDate.add('days', 1));
            }else{
                calendar.fullCalendar( 'select', endDate, startDate.add('days', 1));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(start, end, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
         .. 
        ....
         .. 
        calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
    }
});
```

Comment: I will check it. Appreciate your efforts to try it, thank you

Answer (score -2):

From my experience i never found calender as a good option for such tasks. Try using datepicker instead - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Comment: This is completely different from what I have asked