# How can we specify custom date range with fullcalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to use fullcalendar with custom date range for ex. it should display view for particular date range like from 15th April to 4th May(Spans between two months).

Any suggestions?.

Comment: did you do it? i am having the same situation

Answer (score 2):

you can call this function to gt events in date range. but this will bring you only 30 days evnt. if you pass dates like '01-may-2013' to 15-June-2013' then it will show data from 01-may2013 to 30st may 2013. Lt me know if you can find any clue for this issue.

```
function GetAgendaEvents(datefrom, dateTo) {

    var fromDate = new Date($("#from").val());
    var toDate = new Date($("#to").val());

    if (fromDate.getTime() <= toDate.getTime()) {

        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEvents').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

        var filteredEvent = $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function (event) {
            return event.start >= fromDate && event.start <= toDate;

        });
       $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('gotoDate', fromDate.getFullYear(), fromDate.getMonth(), fromDate.getDate());
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agenda'/* or 'basicDay' */);

        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('removeEvents').fullCalendar('addEventSource', filteredEvent);
        $('#fullcal').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');



    }

}
```